# How to change color of comment marker for Atom editor?

Tags: less, editor, customization, syntax-highlighting, atom-editor

I was able to change color of comment content with

```
atom-text-editor::shadow .comment {
  color: #E4F4FD;
}
```

But the color of comment marker stayed unchanged:

[image]

How do I change the color of comment marker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you place your cursor immediately to the left of the character you want to style and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> all of the scopes for that character will be displayed in an information box:

[image: Screenshot of Scopes at Cursor]

You can then incorporate this into your stylesheet as you have with the body of the comment:

```
atom-text-editor::shadow {
  .comment {
    color: #E4F4FD;
  }

  .punctuation.definition.comment {
    color: #E4F4FD;
  }
}
```

Because it is LESS, it is possible to nest classes which will make your style sheet much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Using ATOM version 1.58.0 on Windows 10, I get a depreciation warning. The short version is:

*Starting from Atom v1.13.0, the contents of atom-text-editor elements are no longer encapsulated within a shadow DOM boundary. This means you should stop using :host and ::shadow pseudo-selectors, and prepend all your syntax selectors with syntax--.*

I had to use:

```
// Change the color of the comments
atom-text-editor .syntax--comment{ color:#9DA5B3; }
atom-text-editor .syntax--punctuation.syntax--definition.syntax--comment{ color:#9DA5B3; }
```